# Simple Calculator Test

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

When I process my code in the browser all I get is this:

[image]

I use the following code that does not work as intended:

```
function compute() {
    p=document.getElementById("principal").value;
    r=document.getElementById("rate").value;
    n=document.getElementById("years").value;
    result=document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML="If you deposit " + p + ",";
    result.innerHTML="at an interest rate of " + r + ".";
    result.innerHTML="in the year " + (newDate - n);
    result.innerHTML="You will receive an amount of " + (p*n*r/100) + ",";

}
```

Comment: and what does it supposed show? is that function being executed at all?

Comment: also, you are overwriting the value every time with `result.innerHTML=`....

Comment: Don't make maths with strings, sooner or later it will bite you, and create a single string for `innerHTML` to set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getresult() {
    var result = '';
    result += 'If you deposit:P' +
        'at an interest rate of R' +
        'in the year Y' +
        'You will receive an amount of R';
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a small number of modifications, the compute function should work very well.

The changes:

- Ensure all our input values are converted to numbers.
- Create a result output element (id="result") to show the results.
- Append output to result string, then assign this to result element innerHTML.
- Create `getFutureValue` function to get total amount after n years.

```js
function getFutureValue(principal, interestRatePercent, termYears) {
    return principal*Math.pow(1 + interestRatePercent/100, termYears);
}

function showResult(result) { 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

function compute() {
    // Ensure all values are _numbers_
    p = Number(document.getElementById("principal").value);
    r = Number(document.getElementById("rate").value);
    n = Number(document.getElementById("years").value);
   
    const newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setFullYear(newDate.getFullYear() + n);
    let result = "If you deposit $" + p + ", ";
    result += "at an interest rate of " + r + "%, ";
    result += "in the year " + (newDate.getFullYear());
    result += ", you will receive an amount of $" + getFutureValue(p, r, n).toFixed(2);
    showResult(result);

}
compute()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
<form class="p-3">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="principal" class="form-label" >Amount</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="principal" value="1000">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="rate" class="form-label">Interest Rate</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="rate" value="3.5">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="years" class="form-label">No. of Years</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="years" value="25">
  </div>
  <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="compute()">Compute Interest</button>
  <div class="mb-3 mt-4">
    <label for="result" class="form-label">Result</label>
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```